# nifi FlowFile has not been closed (Groovy script)warning

Tags: hadoop, groovy, cloudera, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform

new to nifi terminologies and flowfile handling.

Found a convenient way to handle incoming xml and parse it using XmlSlurper, but getting a warning for the below GroovyScript for incoming flowfiles-

the flow:
[image]

processor details:
[image]

script body:

```
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
InputStream i = flowFile.read()
new XmlSlurper().parse(i)
i.close()
REL_SUCCESS << flowFile
```

Seems like issue with handling the flowfile. Can someone explain what exactly is happening here and how to best handle it? seems like this is causing the cluster to hang at times
[image: warning]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `try-catch` or `withStream` to close stream even if error occured:

```
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
def xml = flowFile.read().withStream{i->
    new XmlSlurper().parse(i)
}
REL_SUCCESS << flowFile
```

Comment: It seems to do the work, but processor still shows in/out counter 1 with the parse error. the idea is to parse the xml, if wellformed then pass to success, if not pass to failure connector, suppressing the errors if any during parsing.

http://funkyimg.com/i/2JN6z.jpg

Comment: Update: The counter was just the current flow status with the failed flowfiles. It would show for a minute and disappear along with the error on the processor. so we are good! :) 

I'm wondering whats the easiest method to redirect those parsing errors to a log file, maybe on hdfs? so that I can look back and trace what parsing error occurred for failed flowfiles

Comment: if you use `transfer to failure` Failure strategy then a new parameter will appear in your flow file: `ERROR_MESSAGE` and it will contain error message. so you can transfer error where you want.

Comment: I have transfer to failure connector redirected to another hdfs dir and I am getting the malformed xmls, but how do I use the error_message param to write logs in hdfs? Are you suggesting to use some intermittent processor before pushing the failed files to hdfs?

Once again thanks for your patience daggett!

Comment: right, after storing to hdfs malformed xml, transform the flow file content using error_message and store it nearby the malformed file but with some suffix `.error` for example.

Comment: Which processor should I use for that operation? and where to set the "error_message" property?

Comment: ReplaceText could replace entire flow file content with attribute value

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DhTs5Ui
used replaceText processor with replc value as "ERROR_MESSAGE", but getting flowfile content replaced with literal ERROR_MESSAGE in them. How do I use property variable ? tried {'error_message'} etc but dont seem to work. any help?

Comment: Update: bad typo.. missed the "$" while calling the key. working now... thanks Dagget! :)